# why executation time of tf.nn.conv2d function different while the multiply times are the same?

Tags: performance, tensorflow, deep-learning, convolution, conv-neural-network

I am using tensorflow to build `cnn net` in image classification experiment，I found such phenomenon as:

operation 1：`tf.nn.conv2d(x, [3,3,32,32], strides=[1,1,1,1], padding='SAME')`

the shape of x is `[128,128,32]`，means convolution using 3x3 kernel on x，both input channels and output channels are 32，the total multiply times is

```
3*3*32*32*128*128=150994944
```

operation 2：`tf.nn.conv2d(x, [3,3,64,64], strides=[1,1,1,1], padding='SAME')`

the shape of x is `[64,64,64]`，means convolution using 3x3 kernel on x，both input channels and output channels are 64，the total multiply times is

```
3*3*64*64*64*64=150994944
```

In contrast with operation 1，the feature map size of operation 2 scale down to 1/2 and the channel number doubled. The multiply times are the same so the running time should be same.But in practice the running time of operation 1 is longer than operation 2.

My measure method was shown below

1. eliminate an convolution of operation 1，the training time for one epoch reduced 23 seconds，means the running time of operation 1 is 23 seconds.
2. eliminate an convolution of operation 2，the training time for one epoch reduced 13 seconds，means the running time of operation 2 is 13 seconds.

the phenomenon can reproduction every time。
My gpu is nvidia `gtx980Ti`，os is ubuntu `16.04`。

So that comes the question: Why the running time of operation 1 was longer than operation 2?

Answer (score 0):

If I had to guess it has to do with how the image is ordered in memory.  Remember that in memory everything is stored in a flattened format.  This means that if you have a tensor of shape [128, 128, 32], the 32 features/channels are stored next to eachover.  Then all of the rows, then all of the columns.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-major_order

Accessing closely packed memory is very important to performance especially  on a GPU which has a large memory bus and is optimized for aligned in order memory access.  In case with the larger image you have to skip around the image more and the memory access is more out of order.  In  case 2 you can do more in order memory access which gives you more speed.  Multiplications are very fast operations.  I bet with a convolution memory access if the bottleneck which limits performance.

Comment: Thank you for your answer chasep255!
" Remember that in memory everything is stored in a flattened format."
Another questions：
Where are the tensor X and filter stored？In PC memory or gpu memory？

Answer (score 0):

chasep255's answer is good and probably correct.

Another possibility (or alternative way of thinking about chasep255's answer) is to consider how caching (all the little hardware tricks that can speed up memory fetches, address mapping, etc) could be producing what you see...

You have basically two things: a stream of X input data and a static filter matrix. In case 1, you have 9*1024 static elements, in case 2 you have 4 times as many. Both cases have the same total multiplication count, but in case 2 the process is finding more of its data where it expects (i.e. where it was last time it was asked for.) Net result: less memory access stalls, more speed.

Comment: Thank you MMN！I am having the same gass with you！